# Правильный путь к файлу

Tags: android

Пытаюсь отправить файл на сервер вот таким образом:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
                filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + uri.getPath();
                File file = new File(filePath);
                fileUploadFacade.post(url, file, new FileUploadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int i, String s) {
                        Log.d("Success ", "upload");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int i, String s, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.d("Error ", "upload");
                    }
                });
```

Вот только получаю ошибку

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/document/primary:DCIM/100ANDRO/1.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

то есть, файл не данному пути не найден.

Пытался указывать без `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, всё равно, файл не найден. Как мне получить пусть к указанному файлу?

**UDP:**

```
uri.getPath(); - /document/primary:DCIM/100ANDRO/1.png
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() - /storage/emulated/0


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (fileAdd.size() <= 5) {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    filePath = uri.getPath();
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ filePath);
                    fileUploadFacade.post(url, file, new FileUploadCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int i, String s) {
                            Log.d("Success ", "upload");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int i, String s, Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.d("Error ", "upload");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: А Вас что-то не то в пути. Что выводит `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`? А что `uri.getPath()`?

Comment: Обнови пост, добавил результат 2х методов

Comment: Я спрашивал про `uri.getPath()`.

Comment: Покажите как инициализируется объект `data`.

Comment: data мне приходит в качестве аргумента метода onActivityResult

Comment: Что возвращает `data.getData().getPath()`?

Comment: /document/primary:DCIM/100ANDRO/1.png , тоже самое что и uri.getPath()

Comment: А путь к файлу – `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/1.png`?

Comment: Подставил в путь /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/1.png, помогло. Вот только как получить его в процессе выполнения? обрезать вручную?

Comment: В теории можно, конечно, вручную обрезать, но это нехорошее решение. Что возвращает `data.getDataString()`?

Comment: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2F100ANDRO%2F1.png

Comment: забываем про файлы и пользуемся потоками

Answer (score 0):

У Вас некорректный путь. Вы написали, что программа выдает ошибку:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/document/primary:DCIM/100ANDRO/1.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

У Вас двоеточие перед `DCIM` и, возможно, в самом конце. Проверьте путь и уберите двоеточия.

---

В подобных ситуациях бывает, что у Вас нет требуемых разрешений. В этом случае, для получения пути к внешней памяти через метод `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, а так же банального чтения памяти нужно иметь на это разрешение.

---

Пропишите в `Manifest.xml` это разрешение:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Оно даст Вам право и читать, и записывать в память.

---

В Android 6 и выше, с этим сложнее — [разрешения на Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: разрешения есть

Comment: @Heaven, я обновил вопрос, возможно поможет. И в 6 андроиде нужно проверять разрешения, даже если они прописаны в манифесте.